# Xfce didn't start after login loop

Tags: xfce

After the login loop my laptop stuck at the debian theme and xfce desktop didn't load in please help im using well till today

Comment: can you give us more information on the issue? what OS are you using, do you see anything in X logs?

Answer (score 0):

At this step, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> to open terminal. Type the following lines to reconfigure the XFCE desktop:

```
rm -rf ~/.cache/sessions
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xfce4-panel
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xfce4-session
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xfce4-settings
```

and reboot.